# preg_capture catch multiple regexp matches

Tags: mysql, regex, blob, user-defined-functions

I have a little problem with UDF function [PREG_CAPTURE](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/index.php#PREG_CAPTURE_SECTION):

```
SELECT id_prod, id_lang, description, preg_capture('/D[[:digit:]]{4}/', description) AS Dxxxx FROM works
```

With this query I got `[BLOB - 5 B]`

But when I use parameter in query:

```
SELECT id_prod, id_lang, description, preg_capture('/D[[:digit:]]{4}/', description, 2) AS Dxxxx FROM
```

I got NULL values.
[Here is example of my table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68670/1)
How to get all matches from the description like: D0313, D0320 and go thru with BLOB?

Comment: What's the definition of `preg_capture()`?

Comment: @Barmar http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/index.php

Comment: Your regular expression doesn't have any capture groups. Why do you expect it to return something when you asked for group 2?

Comment: I forgot: When I query: SELECT id_prod, id_lang, description, preg_capture('/D[[:digit:]]{4}/', description, 'gname', 2) AS Dxxxx FROM... also got NULL values.

Comment: There's no capture group named `gname`. Do you know what a _capture group_ is?

Comment: Now, I guess no...googling, or maybe you know some examples?

Comment: www.regular-expressions.info is the place to go to learn all about regular expressions. Capture groups are indicated with (parentheses) in the RE. But I don't think you need them, since you're just interested in the part of the string that matches the whole RE. That's what `preg_capture` returns by default, so I'm not sure why that's not working for you.

Comment: Query: `SELECT id_product, id_lang, description, CONVERT(preg_capture('/D[[:digit:]]{4}/', description,0,1) USING 'utf8') AS Dxxxx FROM works` I got no BLOB error anymore and function catch a RE. But how to catch all RE from each row like CONCAT?

Comment: I don't think the function can do that, it only returns one match at a time.

Comment: So now everything is clear with this question, thanks @Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

Try with conversion to char:

```
SELECT id_prod, id_lang, description, CAST(preg_capture('/D[[:digit:]]{4}/', description)  AS CHAR(10000)) AS Dxxxx FROM works;
```